# MVC 5 Html.LabelFor without using model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a complex model object that contains a number of child objects detailing the page status, data and configuration.  The model's children are defined as base classes and are actually passed as instances of descendant classes and passed to the view to be rendered.

I have the model object being passed OK and I can create local variables that hold the data and config objects but now I want to display some values in text boxes and their labels.

Here is the variable creation in the view:

```
@model PageBase
@{
    PageConfigPersonal config = (PageConfigPersonal)Model.PageConfig;
    PageDataPersonal data = (PageDataPersonal)Model.PageData;
}
```

I can't figure out how, or if, Html.TextBoxFor can be used with these local variables - can this be done and if so how?

I know that I can cast the model but that is going to get really unwieldy and messy so would like to use the local variable instead.

Gordon

Answer (score 1):

still you can use your local variable for TextBoxFor as below,

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => config.<model variable name>)
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct as the Lambda expression must return a property inside the model, `config` is not

Comment: I can confirm that using m => data.Name results in a control with an id of "config.Name" which does not work well when posting back to the server.  At the moment I am casting using ((PageDataPersonal)m.PageData).Name and this is working although it is a handful to type.  I was just looking for a simpler way.